# Highcharts pointInterval

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts

[*Please check image link below*]

[Line Graph with 2 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWgrr.png)

I just want to ignore the pointInterval attribute that from 10:54 AM, the next data would be 05:00 pm (just for example). Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible,

you can pass the timestamp of the points that needs to be mapped

the data should be some thing like this

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28]
]
```

or instead you can use the time stamp as well
then it will be like this

```
data: [
    [22723200000, 0],
    [23846400000, 0.28]
]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried Date.UTC a while ago and it works. Thank you